# return data from an array based on filters

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following array

```
person = [ {name: 'bob', weight: '160 lbs', hair: 'brown'},
            {name: 'bob', weight: '160 lbs', hair: 'brown'},
            {name: 'bob1', weight: '160 lbs', hair: 'brown'}, 
            {name: 'bob1',  weight: '160 lbs', hair: 'brown'}, 
            {name: 'bob1',  weight: '160 lbs', hair: 'brown'} 
]
```

I am trying to get the data from array based on input params name and hair so they can be passed as single or in combination.

I tried following code and it works when name and hair are passed but if i just pass hair, it returns error `undefined local variable or method name`.

Here are the cases i am trying to achieve:
If name = bob and hair = brown passed it should return the first two hash having name: 'bob' and for bob1 last three hash having name: 'bob1' and If only weight or hair is passed it should return the entire array.

I believe i can write conditions based on parameters e.g `if name && hair`, `if hair` but then i'll have to repeat the code where i am selecting from array. So trying to figure out if it could be done with more cleaner way.

how can i update it so i could pass name, hair and also weight, one or in combination?

```
person.select { |hash| hash[:name] == name && hash[:hair] == hair  }
```

The code I am executing is:

```
person = [ {name: 'bob', weight: '160 lbs', hair: 'brown'},
            {name: 'bob', weight: '160 lbs', hair: 'brown'},
            {name: 'bob1', weight: '160 lbs', hair: 'brown'}, 
            {name: 'bob1',  weight: '160 lbs', hair: 'brown'}, 
            {name: 'bob1',  weight: '160 lbs', hair: 'brown'} 
]

# hair = 'brown'
# name = 'bob'
# person.select { |hash| hash[:name] == name &&
#                         hash[:hair] == hair  }
#   -->[{:name=>"bob", :weight=>"160 lbs", :hair=>"brown"}, {:name=>"bob", :weight=>"160 lbs", :hair=>"brown"}]                      

# hair = 'brown'
# name = 'bob1'
# person.select { |hash| hash[:name] == name &&
#                         hash[:hair] == hair  }
  # -->[{:name=>"bob1", :weight=>"160 lbs", :hair=>"brown"}, {:name=>"bob1", :weight=>"160 lbs", :hair=>"brown"}, {:name=>"bob1", :weight=>"160 lbs", :hair=>"brown"}]

hair = 'brown'
person.select { |hash| hash[:name] == name &&
                        hash[:hair] == hair  }
# --> return entire person array
```

Comment: @SebastianPalma If i am correct you asking about 3rd case. in 3rd case i am just trying to pass hair so it returns entire array.

Comment: then simply remove the `hash[:name] == name &&`

Comment: @JoshBrody i am trying to make it dynamic so i could pass one or more params. is it possible?

Comment: Anything is possible but I think you're asking the wrong question. In the body of your question can you provide what your desired input would be, and wha you would expect your output to be?

Comment: my bad. i updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
person = [
  { name: 'Bob',      weight: '160 lbs', hair: 'brown' },
  { name: 'Bub',      weight: '170 lbs', hair: 'none'  },
  { name: 'Wilma',    weight: '160 lbs', hair: 'brown' }, 
  { name: 'Gertrude', weight: '120 lbs', hair: 'blue'  }, 
  { name: 'Bob',      weight: '160 lbs', hair: 'brown' } 
]

def select_matches(person, target)
  keys = target.keys
  person.select { |h| h.select { |k| keys.include?(k) } == target }
end 

select_matches(person, name: 'Bob', weight: '160 lbs', hair: 'brown')
  #=> [{:name=>"Bob", :weight=>"160 lbs", :hair=>"brown"},
  #    {:name=>"Bob", :weight=>"160 lbs", :hair=>"brown"}]
select_matches(person, weight: '160 lbs', hair: 'brown')
  #=> [{:name=>"Bob", :weight=>"160 lbs", :hair=>"brown"},
  #    {:name=>"Wilma", :weight=>"160 lbs", :hair=>"brown"},
  #    {:name=>"Bob", :weight=>"160 lbs", :hair=>"brown"}] 
select_matches(person, name: 'Gertrude')
  #=> [{:name=>"Gertrude", :weight=>"120", :hair=>"blue"}]
```

Note that

```
select_matches(person, weight: '160 lbs', hair: 'brown')
```

is shorthand for

```
select_matches(person, { weight: '160 lbs', hair: 'brown' })
```

In Ruby 2.5 the penultimate line can be written

```
person.select { |h| h.slice(*keys) == target }
```

See [Hash#slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-slice). Slice is nice, eh?